# Should we compare new state with old state in the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using spread operator in the reducer function, so what is happening when i am dispatching the action then it is creating new state (obj) even old state is same as like new state so it is re-rendering react component.

Is it good approach to compare new state with old state as object could be complex ? Deep comparison ?

```
const initialState = {};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action: any = {}): any => {
  if (action.type === ActionTypes.RC) {
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.config,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Or redux does it out of the box for you in mapStateToProps ?

Comment: Why are you dispatching the action when the state should not update?

Comment: i am dispatching config action from multiple pages, so even old state is same as like new state then it re-renders everything.

Comment: You need the processing time either for performing the deep equals or for the re-render. Maybe the deep equals might be faster (guess) but as long as you don't have any performance problem I think you shouldn't care about it.

Comment: just override ‘shouldcomponentupdate’ it you are using class based components. you can compare if props are changed there and avoid re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few things worth noting here.

React Redux uses strict equality (reference equality) as the default method for comparisons. The immutable nature of Redux state means that any change to a deeply-nested property requires that all of its ancestor must be new object references.

If you update `a.b.c` then `a` and `a.b` must be new objects. Let's say that you have a sibling property tree like `a.d.e`. When you update `a.b.c` it causes `a` to be a new object reference, but `a.d` and `a.d.e` are the same.  If you have a component that only needs to know about `a.d` then it should not need to re-render in response to your `a.b.c` change.

This is why it's important that **each component should only select the minimal information that it needs from the state**.  You should [connect more individual components](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store) rather than selecting a lot of information from state and passing it down through props.  You can [use multiple `useSelector` hooks in the same component](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#call-useselector-multiple-times-in-function-components) to select small, granular pieces of state.

---

You do have the ability to [customize the equality comparison](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) by passing a comparison function as the second argument to the `useSelector` hook.

If you have a component that subscribes to the piece of state that's controlled by this reducer then you can use the `shallowEqual` function which is included in the `react-redux` package.  I'm not sure if the reducer in your question is your root reducer or something that you are passing to `combineReducers`.  I'm assuming it's just one piece.
Let's say it's for a property `settings` and you have some `updateSettings` action that merges the new settings with the existing ones.  Then when you have a component that needs to access the settings, you would do this:

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
```

```
const settings = useSelector(state => state.settings, shallowEqual);
```

This would mean that the component will only re-render if some of the settings have actually changed, even if `state.settings` is a new object.  It is doing a shallow comparison between the current value of `state.settings` and the previous one.

It is possible to use a deep equals comparison like lodash's [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) but I'm not seeing why you would need it as this reducer is making a shallow copy.  If you need to do that expensive check anywhere then it seems more logical to do it before you `dispatch` the action in the component or before you return a new object from the reducer rather than on every call of the `useSelector` hook.

You asked about whether you should check for changes in the reducer before returning a new `state` object.  That's a good idea and it's actually what a combined reducer created by `combineReducers` does, though it only checks for shallow equality.  See [lines 177-201 of the source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/c21ac204e8ef1d6d428ee3b906b3646c73aa9441/src/combineReducers.ts#L177-L201).  If all of the individual property reducers returned the same object as before then it will return the previously combined `state` in order to maintain object references.

Comment: Here in my case, i dont think shallowEqual will work in the useSelector. as reducer is creating new object everytime using spread operator or immutable library so last object and new object reference is always different. It will re-render component everytime due to new reference. What do you think ?

Comment: It depends on if it’s a new object at just the top level or a new object at every level of nesting.  The point of the shallow equals comparison is that it ignores the fact that it’s a new object at the top level of whatever value you are returning from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

personal opinion:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]);// <= re-render state diff here
```

The page should be re-render or not is decided by react, or says: will be better.

There's `dom-diff algorithm` in react.

You dispatch action from multiple pages, these pages pick their own state from newState, and diff themselves, trigger re-render or not.

So i think you don't have to run another `diff algorithm` in reducer.

consider case:

You have PageA & PageAB, state { a:1, b:1 }

PageA re-render by a. PageAB re-render by a,b

Now your state become {a:1, b:2}. How could you make PageA not re-render in `reducer`? you will diff it in PageA.